# program giving wrong output for a specific input

Tags: c++, primes

I want to check if a number is prime. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num;
    int i, k = 0;
    cin >> num;
    for(i = 2; i < num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    if(k > 0){
        cout << "The number is not prime" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Prime!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter 6 , 78, ... etc it's giving the correct output.
But when I'm entering 4294967296 which is not a prime number, it's returning `Prime!`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `4294967296` is a rather special number. It is `2^32`, which is limit of the storage capacity of an `int`, which typically holds only 32 bits. Thus, your `num` is interpreted as if it were `0`.

The rest follows logically from that overflow misinterpretation. The `for` loop is never entered, since `2` is not less than `0`, so `k` never gets incremented.

**EDIT** Actually, in this particular case, it fails for a different reason. `std::cin` performs truncation on the input, so when you enter `4294967296`, `num` will actually get assigned the value of `2147483647`. Your program [correctly] prints that that value is prime. It's just that that's not the number the user had intended to test.

Comment: So I need to use a larger data type like `long long`?

Comment: @Sakir For this specific case, yes - you just need a larger type. Probably `unsigned` as well. But your algorithm will be very slow for numbers that large anyway. The largest positive value an `int` can store is `2147483647` - how long does your program take to finish in that case?

Comment: I knew that. It took almost 22 seconds for me. I will use sieve algorithm then :)

Comment: Actually answer is not quite correct. Number is not interpreted as 0, but `std::cin` truncates it to 2147483647. For loop is entered indeed as it takes quite time to provide result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate your input. 4294967296 is too big for 32 bit signed integer, so `std::cin` truncates it to 2147483647 which is actually prime. You can check that printing your number back to screen. You should also change your loop to:

```
for(i = 2; i < num / 2; i++)
```

as it would provide the same result, but decrease calculation time twice.

Comment: You can do *way* better than num/2.

Comment: @Barry yes square root, but this could be good enough comparing what OP has